# Perforce&Swarm: After Submitting a Change Files are Deleted from Workspace

Tags: perforce, swarm

If I submit a changelist in Perforce by creating a new swarm review, the changed files are deleted from my local workspace.
After the changelist is accepted the files reappear (get downloaded?) to my workspace again.

How can I submit a review but keep the files in my workspace so I can work with my changes locally?
(Right now I have to wait until the swarm review is accepted to continue with my work)

- maybe it has something to do with the "Shelve files" option?

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my error.

1. The files are not deleted but shelved (they are stored in the remote repository but I cannot access them locally as the change is not approved
2. Simply do not shelve the files on a new swarm request.

Comment: Or shelve them to get the state-as-reviewed saved on the server, but unshelve them and continue working with them locally. Generally speaking, though, aren't you a bit worried about asking for a review of your changes while you're still working on them?